# Mobile app - When should I use splash screen?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, mobile-application

I'm coding a mobile app using React Native, I don't really know when should I show the splash screen, considering these scenarios:

1. App is not opened yet -> user open the app -> (show splash screen?) -> show login screen.
2. App is opened in background -> user is not loged in -> user open the app -> (show splash screen?) -> show login screen.
3. App is opened in background -> user is loged in -> user open the app -> (show splash screen?) -> show home screen.
4. User logout -> (show splash screen?) -> show login screen.

The first one seems pretty normal but I'm not sure about the other scenarios, should I show a splash screen on those? I might use a splash screen for aesthetic purposes only and barely use it for heavy loading wait time.

Comment: Splash screens are a **very old fashioned** idea.  Never have a splash screen, forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using splash screen in your first scenario when loading your app, assets and fonts.

You may also use it if your app is displaying sensitive data (like bank account infos, etc.) to show the splash screen every time the app is going to the background. Hide the splash screen when the user brings the app back to the foreground by displaying a re-login screen.

Otherwise, you could use a global loading state (which is not a very good UI approach).

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

- What is `splash screen`?

> A splash screen is a graphical control element consisting of a window
> containing an image, a logo, and the current version of the software.
> A splash screen can appear while a game or program is launching. A
> splash page is an introduction page on a website. A splash
> screen may cover the entire screen or web page; or may simply be a
> rectangle near the center of the screen or page. The splash screens of
> operating systems and some applications that expect to be run in full
> screen usually cover the entire screen.

- Purpose:

> Splash screens are typically used by particularly large applications
> to notify the user that the program is in the process of loading. They
> provide feedback that a lengthy process is underway. Occasionally, a
> progress bar within the splash screen indicates the loading progress.
> A splash screen disappears when the application's main window appears.
> Splash screens may be added for a period of time and then replaced
> anew.

- when to use it?

> - to direct users to the appropriate website for their country or language preference
> - to direct users to a low-bandwidth site or one more accessible to disabled users
> - as an additional form of advertising
> - to restrict access to content such as pornography, alcohol advertising or sales, or gambling
> - as an aesthetic complement to the main page
> - to grab someone's attention to take them to a page with more details usually for a product that they are selling.